# ApexChart Angular 15 CSV Export doesn´t work correctly after update 3.16-> 3.45

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I´m working with Angular (v 15) after update ApexChart from v 3.35 to v 3.45 and test the functions to export data to CSV File, I found a problem with the format.
**Note**
I update ApexChart to solve a problem that produce I can´t export a CSV in case of incompleted series of data.
**
[Before the update i get this format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2VDY.png)

[After:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8fm0.png)

I try to change some options of export csv function and adjusting the formatter method on chartOption Object:

```
this.chartOptions = {
      series: this.mapChartData(this.timelineData),
      chart: {
        height: this.height,
        type: "rangeBar",
        animations:{
          enabled: false,
        },
        zoom: {
          autoScaleYaxis: true
        },
        toolbar: {
          show: true,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          export: {
            csv: {
              filename: `timeline ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`,
              columnDelimiter: ', ',
              headerCategory: 'category',
              headerValue: 'value',
              dateFormatter(timestamp) {
                return timestamp;
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: true,
          barHeight: this.parameters.BarHeightPixels + 'px', //Alto de la barra dinamico
          rangeBarGroupRows: true,
        }
      },
      colors: this.mapChartColor(this.timelineData), //Agregado color dinamico
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: [],
        tickAmount: 60, //cantidad de ticks en el eje X 'dataPoints'
        tickPlacement: 'between',
        /* MIN PARA CUANDO ESTE DISPONIBLE EL CAMBIO EN EL ENDPOINT
        min: this.timelineData.TimeAxisMin ? moment(this.datetimePipe.transform(this.timelineData.TimeAxisMin)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : undefined, */
        /* min: new Date('25 Aug 2022 00:00').getTime(), */
        min: this.getFormattedMinMaxDateTimestamp(this.timelineData.TimeAxisMin, this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat),
        max: this.getFormattedMinMaxDateTimestamp(this.timelineData.TimeAxisMax, this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat),
        range: undefined,
        floating: false,
        decimalsInFloat: undefined,
        overwriteCategories: undefined,
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
            show: true,
            rotate: -70,
            rotateAlways: true,
            hideOverlappingLabels: false,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: this.labelMinHeight,
            maxHeight: this.labelMaxHeight,
            style: {
                colors: [],
                fontSize: '11px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
            },
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            format: this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat,
            formatter(timestamp, value, opts) {
              let formatoFecha: any;
              try {
                formatoFecha = opts.w.config.xaxis.labels.format
              } catch (error) {
                formatoFecha =opts.config.xaxis.labels.format;
              }

              try {  
                opts.globals.seriesRangeStart.map(data => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = data[i] ? moment(new Date(data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : data[i];
                  }
                });
                opts.globals.seriesRangeEnd.map(data => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = data[i] ? moment(new Date(data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : data[i];
                  }
                });
                opts.globals.series.map(data => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i] = data[i] ? moment(new Date(data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : data[i];
                  }
                });
                return moment(new Date(timestamp)).format(formatoFecha);
              } catch (error) {
                return moment(new Date(timestamp)).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
              }
            },
            datetimeUTC: true,
            datetimeFormatter: { },
        },
        axisBorder: {
            show: true,
            color: '#78909C',
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0
        },
        axisTicks: {
            show: true,
            borderType: 'solid',
            color: '#78909C',
            height: 0,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: undefined,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            style: {
                color: undefined,
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 600,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-title',
            },
        },
        crosshairs: {
            show: true,
            width: 1,
            position: 'back',
            opacity: 0.9,
            stroke: {
                color: '#b6b6b6',
                width: 0,
                dashArray: 0,
            },
            fill: {
                type: 'solid',
                color: '#B1B9C4',
                gradient: {
                    colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
                    colorTo: '#BED1E6',
                    stops: [0, 100],
                    opacityFrom: 0.4,
                    opacityTo: 0.5,
                },
            },
            dropShadow: {
                enabled: false,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                blur: 1,
                opacity: 0.4,
            },
        },
      },
      //MANEJA LA GRILLA INTERNA DEL GRAFICO//
      grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: '#90A4AE',
        strokeDashArray: 0,
        position: 'back',
        xaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        row: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        column: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 55,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 35
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        labels: {
          show: false,
          offsetX: 0,
          rotate: -90,
        },
      },
      fill: {
        type: "gradient",
        gradient: {
          shade: "light",
          type: "vertical",
          shadeIntensity: 0.25,
          gradientToColors: undefined,
          inverseColors: true,
          opacityFrom: 1,
          opacityTo: 1,
          stops: [50, 0, 100, 100]
        }
      },
      legend: {
        show: true,
        showForSingleSeries: true,
        showForZeroSeries: true,
        position: "top",
        horizontalAlign: "left"
      },
      tooltip: {
        custom: function (opts) {
          const fromYear = moment(opts.y1).format('DD/MM HH:mm');
          const toYear = moment(opts.y2).format('DD/MM HH:mm');
          const values = opts.ctx.rangeBar.getTooltipValues(opts);

          return (
            '<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-rangebar" style="font-size:10px">' +
            '<div> <span class="series-name">' +
            values.ylabel+
            "</span></div>" +
            '<div> <span class="category" style="color:' + values.color +  '">' +
            (values.seriesName ? values.seriesName : "") +
            ' </span> </br> <strong> <span class="value start-value">' +
            fromYear +
            '</span> </br> <span class="value end-value">' +
            toYear +
            "</span> </strong></div>" +
            "</div>"
          );
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

after changes:

```
this.chartOptions = {
      series: this.mapChartData(this.timelineData),
      chart: {
        height: this.height,
        type: "rangeBar",
        animations:{
          enabled: false,
        },
        zoom: {
          autoScaleYaxis: true
        },
        toolbar: {
          show: true,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          export: {
            csv: {
              filename: `timeline ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`,
              columnDelimiter: ', ',
              headerCategory: 'category',
              headerValue: 'value',
              dateFormatter(timestamp) {
                console.log(timestamp);
                return timestamp
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: true,
          barHeight: this.parameters.BarHeightPixels + 'px', //Alto de la barra dinamico
          rangeBarGroupRows: true,
        }
      },
      colors: this.mapChartColor(this.timelineData), //Agregado color dinamico
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        categories: [],
        tickAmount: 60, //cantidad de ticks en el eje X 'dataPoints'
        tickPlacement: 'between',
        /* MIN PARA CUANDO ESTE DISPONIBLE EL CAMBIO EN EL ENDPOINT
        min: this.timelineData.TimeAxisMin ? moment(this.datetimePipe.transform(this.timelineData.TimeAxisMin)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : undefined, */
        /* min: new Date('25 Aug 2022 00:00').getTime(), */
        min: this.getFormattedMinMaxDateTimestamp(this.timelineData.TimeAxisMin, this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat),
        max: this.getFormattedMinMaxDateTimestamp(this.timelineData.TimeAxisMax, this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat),
        range: undefined,
        floating: false,
        decimalsInFloat: undefined,
        overwriteCategories: undefined,
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
            show: true,
            rotate: -70,
            rotateAlways: true,
            hideOverlappingLabels: false,
            showDuplicates: false,
            trim: false,
            minHeight: this.labelMinHeight,
            maxHeight: this.labelMaxHeight,
            style: {
                colors: [],
                fontSize: '11px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
            },
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            format: this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat,
            formatter(timestamp, value, opts) {
              let formatoFecha: any;
              try {
                formatoFecha = opts.w.config.xaxis.labels.format
              } catch (error) {
                formatoFecha =opts.config.xaxis.labels.format;
              }
              try { 
                opts.w.globals.seriesRange.map(x => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });

                opts.w.globals.seriesRangeStart.map(x => {

                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });
                opts.w.globals.seriesRangeEnd.map(x => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });
                opts.w.globals.series.map(x => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });

                opts.globals.seriesRange.map(x => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });

                opts.globals.seriesRangeStart.map(x => {

                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });
                opts.globals.seriesRangeEnd.map(x => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });
                opts.globals.series.map(x => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < x.data.length; i++) {
                    x.data[i] = x.data[i] ? moment(new Date(x.data[i])).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : x.data[i];
                  }
                });
                return moment(new Date(timestamp)).format(formatoFecha);
              } catch (error) {
                return moment(new Date(timestamp)).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
              }
            },
            datetimeUTC: true,
            datetimeFormatter: { },
        },
        axisBorder: {
            show: true,
            color: '#78909C',
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0
        },
        axisTicks: {
            show: true,
            borderType: 'solid',
            color: '#78909C',
            height: 0,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: undefined,
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
            style: {
                color: undefined,
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 600,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-title',
            },
        },
        crosshairs: {
            show: true,
            width: 1,
            position: 'back',
            opacity: 0.9,
            stroke: {
                color: '#b6b6b6',
                width: 0,
                dashArray: 0,
            },
            fill: {
                type: 'solid',
                color: '#B1B9C4',
                gradient: {
                    colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
                    colorTo: '#BED1E6',
                    stops: [0, 100],
                    opacityFrom: 0.4,
                    opacityTo: 0.5,
                },
            },
            dropShadow: {
                enabled: false,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                blur: 1,
                opacity: 0.4,
            },
        },
      },
      //MANEJA LA GRILLA INTERNA DEL GRAFICO//
      grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: '#90A4AE',
        strokeDashArray: 0,
        position: 'back',
        xaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            lines: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        row: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        column: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 55,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 35
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        labels: {
          show: false,
          offsetX: 0,
          rotate: -90,
        },
      },
      fill: {
        type: "gradient",
        gradient: {
          shade: "light",
          type: "vertical",
          shadeIntensity: 0.25,
          gradientToColors: undefined,
          inverseColors: true,
          opacityFrom: 1,
          opacityTo: 1,
          stops: [50, 0, 100, 100]
        }
      },
      legend: {
        show: true,
        showForSingleSeries: true,
        showForZeroSeries: true,
        position: "top",
        horizontalAlign: "left"
      },
      tooltip: {
        custom: ({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w })=> {

          var serie = w.globals.initialSeries[seriesIndex];
          const fromYear = moment(serie.data[dataPointIndex].y[0]).format(this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat);
          const toYear = moment(serie.data[dataPointIndex].y[1]).format(this.timelineData.TimeAxisFormat);
          return (
            '<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-rangebar" style="font-size:10px">' +
            '<div> <span class="series-name">' +
            serie.data[dataPointIndex].x +
            "</span></div>" +
            '<div> <span class="category" style="color:' +serie.color +'">' +
            (serie.name ? serie.name : "") +
            ' </span> </br> <strong> <span class="value start-value">' +
            fromYear +
            '</span> </br> <span class="value end-value">' +
            toYear +
            "</span> </strong></div>" +
            "</div>"
          );
        }
      },
    }
```

Any suggestions?